# Using a user defined function in R DataFrame with dplyr

Tags: r, function, paste, dplyr

It is possible to use a user defined function in dplyr. But if I use the following code:

```
create_string <- function(n) {
 new_string <- paste(c(0:n), collapse=';')
 return(new_string)
}

df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, number = c('4', '2', '1'), expected = c(create_string(4), create_string(2), create_string(1)))

df %>% mutate(reality = create_string(number))
```

The output is equal to:

```
  x number  expected   reality
1 1      4 0;1;2;3;4 0;1;2;3;4
2 2      2     0;1;2 0;1;2;3;4
3 3      1       0;1 0;1;2;3;4
Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `reality`.
i numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
i Input `reality` is `create_string(number)`. 
2: In 0:n : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
```

So you can see that the expected output is not equal to the reality (errors included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `mutate` is filling this for all rows at a time, which means unstead of `create_string(4)`, you're actually getting `create_string(c(4,2,1))`. The solution is to somehow force execution to be on one value at a time.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(reality = sapply(number, create_string))
#   x number  expected   reality
# 1 1      4 0;1;2;3;4 0;1;2;3;4
# 2 2      2     0;1;2     0;1;2
# 3 3      1       0;1       0;1
```

Alternatives:

```r
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(reality = create_string(number)) %>%
  ungroup()

df %>% mutate(reality = purrr::map_chr(number, create_string))
df %>% mutate(reality = Vectorize(create_string)(number))
```

Or you can vectorize your function internally:

```r
create_string <- function(n) {
 new_string <- sapply(n, function(n0) paste(c(0:n0), collapse=';'))
 return(new_string)
}
df %>%
  mutate(reality = create_string(number))
#   x number  expected   reality
# 1 1      4 0;1;2;3;4 0;1;2;3;4
# 2 2      2     0;1;2     0;1;2
# 3 3      1       0;1       0;1
```